# does a c Struct have scope amongst its members?

Tags: c

Ex:

```
struct foo
{
 /* Scope? */
int a;
int b;

};
```

is there any scope in this struct's body?
Does b know that a exist?

Comment: i believe it does. `struct.member` vs `member` are different variables.

Comment: Are there statements in the structure's body? If not, what does it mean to have scope where statements aren't even allowed?

Comment: If you are in C and not C++, then there is no scope because C structs do not have methods.

Comment: @true Those are namespaces, not scopes, and on top of that clearly have nothing to do with the question, which is about visibility within the curlies above.

Answer (score 3):

No. As 6.2.1/2 says, C language only has file scope, function scope, block scope and prototype scope. There are no other scopes in C.

A struct type does not create a scope. For example, any new type declared between the `{}` will belong to the enclosing scope. E.g. if you declare this in file scope

```
 struct foo
 {
   struct bar
   {
     int x;
   } b;
 } a;
```

then the "nested" `struct bar` type definition will belong to file scope as well. I.e. you'll be able to immediately use

```
struct bar b;
```

at file scope. That `struct bar` will refer to the "nested " `struct bar` type definition above (meaning essentially that it is not really "nested").

Note also that C language has a concept of *name spaces*, into which different kinds of identifiers are placed and in which they later are looked up. Each struct type gets its own *name space* into which the names of the struct members are placed. However, the concept of *name space* is different from the concept of *scope*, even though they work in concert.

It is not clear what you mean by "does `b` know that `a` exist". C language does not provide you with any means to write code that depends on what `b` "knows" and what it "doesn't know". This makes your question moot.

Comment: true, would you please elaborate.struct.member vs member?

Comment: @Unee0x: C language specification says that struct members live in a separate *name space* associated with that struct type. But it is a different concept. Namespace is not scope.

Comment: @Unee0x If you want to respond to a user, put an "@" in front of their name, and put your response in the right place ... true commented under your question, not under Andrey's answer. Anyway, true's comment is  irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score -3):

Do you mean, "Can I refer to a struct foo in the declaration of struct foo"?

Example:

```
struct foo
{
   ...
   struct foo next;
   ...
}
```

If the above is what you want, then yes, it is valid.

Comment: This is not valid, it attempts to create an infinitely sized struct. `struct foo *next;` would be valid.

Comment: Aside from being invalid, no, that's not what the OP meant. Please don't ask questions in answers, post them as comments ... once you have enough rep to do so.